# pscp between linux and windows

Tags: linux, pscp

I am trying to scp file(s) from window to linux.
user is windows system, we are executing pscp from linux command
Command used :

```
pscp user@ip:source dest
```

It shows :

```
unable to identify source: permission denied
```

If I use it in this way,

```
pscp source user@ip:dest
```

It works fine and copy the files to windows.

Am I using correct format?

We need to copy from remote windows, but the commands needs to be invoked from local linux system.

Comment: Off-topic; stackoverflow is about programming - for general use try https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I copy a file from my windows machine to my linux machine

> C:\Users...\Downloads>pscp -i "DEV_IRM.ppk"
>   product-sp-4.2.0-rc2.tar.gz
>   prvclouduser@10.149.137.26:/home/prvclouduser/sp420

Make sure that you are in the directory where the file you want to copy is located. In my case 'Downloads' directory.

Private key for access: DEV_IRM.ppk

My linux server: prvclouduser@10.149.137.26

The landing directory in linux: /home/prvclouduser/sp420 (make sure this exists; do pwd to confirm full path)